# VBA - Comparison anomalies using variant

Tags: excel, vba, variants

I have found a couple of other questions dealing with variants but none of them seem to address my issue.

I have very simple for loops doing comparisons. The purpose is to color the Excel cell red if there isn't a match. The results are 99% accurate, but I have noticed a couple of seemingly random errors. For example, a cell containing the number 104875 is not colored red, which indicates that there should be a matching cell in the comparison column. But there isn't. It seems like they should all be wrong or all be correct. Some of the other threads about variants have mentioned that the comparisons have to be of the same type or you will get weird errors. In my case, they are of the same type (both integers), so this isn't the problem.

I am brand new to VBA and still trying to understand how it works.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim array1() As Variant, array2() As Variant
Dim column1 As Double
Dim column2 As Double

column1 = convertColumn(TextBox1.Text)
column2 = convertColumn(TextBox2.Text)

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Advocate July 2017 Data.xlsm").Sheets(1)
Set wb2 = Workbooks("BI Report 8-18-17.xlsm").Sheets(1)

array1 = Intersect(wb1.Columns(column1), wb1.UsedRange)
array2 = Intersect(wb2.Columns(column2), wb2.UsedRange)


For i = 2 To UBound(array1)
    flag = False
    For j = 2 To UBound(array2)
        If IsNumeric(array1(i, 1)) And IsNumeric(array2(j, 1)) Then If CDbl(array1(i, 1)) = CDbl(array2(j, 1)) Then flag = True
        Next j
    If Not flag Then wb1.Cells(i, column1).Interior.Color = vbRed
Next i
End Sub
```

EDIT: Turns out that my code works fine. The problem was simply that some of the cells on one of the sheets were hidden and I didn't realize it. ~facepalm~ that's what I get for being inexperienced in excell

Comment: Can you give an example where the compare fails? Are you sure you deal with integers or do you (sometimes) deal with strings looking like an integer?

Comment: If it is random, look at the false positives/negatives in the data and see why they are wrong.  The error is in the data.  As a side note `Dim i, j As Integer` i is being declared as a variant not an Integer. `Dim i As Integer, j As Integer`

Comment: It might be helpful to someone attempting to answer this if a sample spreadsheet that reproduces the problem, or description of data to reproduce, were provided.

Comment: FunThomas: For example, when I run the program, the cell containing "104875" is not colored red, indicating that there is a match in the comparison column. But when I do a ctrl+F search for that number in the other file, nothing is found. I'm dealing with about 9000 rows, so it isn't practical for me to do a manual search.

Comment: Also that inner condition could be removed an use explicit type conversions - it's never crystal-clear exactly what's going on when you compare two `Variant` values. `flag = CDbl(array1(i, 1)) = CDbl(array2(j, 1))`.

Comment: Matt's Mug: Thanks. See my comment to FunThomas for an example.

Comment: @Sherlock 104,875 is larger than 32,768, it is not an `Integer`. Numeric cell values are always `Double`, but could be a `String` if you've formatted the cell as text. Avoid problems, avoid `Variant` comparisons, and use explicit type conversions. Also your code will blow up if any cell value contains an error, e.g. `#VALUE!` or `#DIV/0!` or whatever.

Comment: @Mat's Mug: I tried using CDbl(array1(i,1)) = CDbl(array1(j, 1)) and it gave me a type mismatch error.

Comment: Bingo. One of your values contains an error value, or a value that otherwise cannot be converted to a numeric value.

Comment: @Mat's Mug: I modified the code slightly to skip over non-numeric values (in which case any non-numeric should automatically be colored red), and 104875 is still not red. (By the way, I changed i and j to Long.) So it seems the type mismatch is not the problem here. This is really baffling.

Comment: You know how to use step-through (F8) and the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) [and breakpoints (F9)]? Insert a `Stop` statement inside the inner loop, e.g. `If array1(i, 1) = 104875 Then Stop`, and then confirm whether `array2(j, 1)` contains the value you think it contains. We can't help you much further than that.

Comment: Ok I did this and it turns out that array2(j,1) = 101048. But why is it returning true???

Comment: @Mat's Mug: Actually, I did it again, and it appears array2(j,1) really does equal 104857. I just noticed that some rows in the second spreadsheet are hidden. I think this might explain why ctrl+F doesn't find the value? I have barely ever used Excel  and never used VB before so I'm really just crash coursing through all this stuff.

Comment: I think at this point your question needs an [edit] with clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify your code, to something easily reproductible. E.g., lets say that you want to compare the first 50 cells in columns **A** and **B** in the activesheet. Put some values and it will look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim array1      As Variant
    Dim array2      As Variant
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Long
    Dim flag        As Boolean

    With ActiveSheet
        array1 = .Range("A1:A50")
        array2 = .Range("B1:B50")
        .Range("A1:A10").Interior.Color = vbWhite

        For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)
            flag = False

            For j = LBound(array2) To UBound(array2)
                If array1(i, 1) = array2(j, 1) Then flag = True
            Next j

            If Not flag Then .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Then try to adapt the solution to yours. It should work.